# android ffmpeg compilation error

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, java-native-interface, makefile

I'm following the steps at [AndroidFFmpeg](https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg) to compile `FFmpeg` for Android.  When I type `./build_android.sh`, I get the following error.

```
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
configure: WARNING: invalid host type: &
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
configure: WARNING: invalid host type: ffmpeg/AndroidFFmpeg/FFmpegLibrary/jni/vo-amrwbenc/../ffmpeg-build/armeabi
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... 
configure: error: unsafe absolute working directory name
```

I'm not getting any clue of what is going wrong. Need little help

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This link might be pretty useful.
http://mingw-users.1079350.n2.nabble.com/configure-error-unsafe-absolute-working-directory-name-td7462094.html
Apparently the error is because of backslash or other special characters in the directory name.

Comment: Thank you @squauria. It was due to special characters in the directory name. I didn't even anticipate it would be this minor issue, I thought to be facing some major issue :)

Comment: from the mingw link above:"The characters it frowns upon are:
\ " # $ & ' `
and 0x0A (also known as \n)."